# Flutter get value in object list

Tags: flutter, dart

In my Home.dart

```
static _getList() async {
  Network network = Network();
  final List list = await network.getData();
  print("jsonString");
  print(list);
  return list;
```

}

Result in console:

flutter: [{id: 1, calc: 000100, name: Test, date: 2018-03-29 12:45:26.9830000}]

I need to get the id's and names of this object and generate a list, to be read

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to convert your json data to objects.

There are tools to help you generating object from json like [json2Dart](https://javiercbk.github.io/json_to_dart/). The result is :

```
class MyObject {
  int id;
  String calc;
  String name;
  String date;

  MyObject({this.id, this.calc, this.name, this.date});

  MyObject.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    id = json['id'];
    calc = json['calc'];
    name = json['name'];
    date = json['date'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['id'] = this.id;
    data['calc'] = this.calc;
    data['name'] = this.name;
    data['date'] = this.date;
    return data;
  }

  @override
  String toString() {
    return '$id';
  }
}
```

You need to iterate over your list from getData() and call MyObject.fromJson() from each occurence :

```
var myObjetcs = [];
for (var item in list) {
  myObjetcs.add(MyObject.fromJson(item));
}

//Now, do what you want with myObjects
```

Hope it will help you

Comment: thank's for answer!, but callback de error in console:  [VERBOSE-2:ui_dart_state.cc(157)] Unhandled Exception: type 'int' is not a subtype of type 'String'

Comment: It's probably because the type of some attributes are not of String type like the id ? where do the error occurs ?

Comment: yes..I got the id, the return on the print is now:
flutter: [Instance of 'MyObject', Instance of 'MyObject', Instance of 'MyObject', Instance of 'MyObject', Instance of 'MyObject', Instance of 'MyObject', Instance of 'MyObject', Instance of 'MyObject', Instance of 'MyObject', Instance of 'MyObject', Instance of 'MyObject', Instance of 'MyObject', Instance of 'MyObject', Instance of 'MyObject', Instance of 'MyObject', Instance of 'MyObject', Instance of 'MyObject', Instance of 'MyObject', Instance of 'MyObject', Instance of 'MyObject', Instance of 'MyObject', Instance of 'MyObject',

Comment: Ok great :)  now you can do what you want with your list ;)

Comment: how can I get, for example in this list only the id and show it in the print

Comment: You can for example override the toString() method of MyObject to print only the id. See my edits.
Or you can create a new list of ids only

Comment: Are you ok with my answer? I'll be grateful if you would upvote and accept it. If you have a new question, you can post a new one. Thanks

Comment: in my list: 
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    MyObject obj = MyObject();
    return DefaultTabController(
      length: 2,
      child: Scaffold(
        drawerDragStartBehavior: DragStartBehavior.down,
        key: _scaffoldKey,
        body: TabBarView(
          dragStartBehavior: DragStartBehavior.down,
          children: <Widget>[
            _buildTab(context, HomeTab.list1, obj),
            _buildTab(context, HomeTab.list2, obj),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

Comment: get a error 405:57: Error: The argument type 'MyObject' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'List<String>'. when use de obj